# How to calculate how many unique not authorized users opened specific url in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express

I'm using ExpressJs and MongoDB. I want to show how many not authorized unique users have opened specific event page. 
How should I implement this request counter ? 
Check IP address or add some mark in cookie...

Comment: Such questions (if they were constructive) would benefit from the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [cookie](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieParser.html) and do something like this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.cookies['track_id'] ||= require('connect').utils.uid(32);
  next();
});
```

Now you could on every site just push the id of the cookie:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.isAuthenticated()){
    statistics.findAndModify(
      {_id: req.url},
      {},
      {$addToSet: {ids: req.cookies['track_id']}},
      {upsert:true}
    );
  }
  next();
});
```

Then you can query in your mongodb database. If you indexed the `ids` field you can query for one id and see which urls they visited, too. The number of visitors is the length of the array.

If you replace `$addToSet` with `$push` you will also track people on the site twice.

Of course, that all falls apart when people delete their cookies ^^

Note that this is untested and I just write it up as I went along. I also assumed you used the plain `node-mongodb-native`, DB query may vary for you. Redis would also be a good solution for this.

Comment: I know it's late but I also want to point to @Stefano_Sanfilippo answer. : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19754996/4108694 for the use of cookies.